# Effect of consts and variablization of operations in C# performance

Tags: c#, c++, performance, optimization

Constants are often used in C/C++ programming as a way of producing clearer code. There may sometimes be an optimization benefit as well. However, I was wondering just what benefit can be gleaned from declaring values to be readonly or consts in C#, aside from more readable code.

Let's say I have the following C# code:

```
public Double HalfPiSomething(Int32 input)
{
    return input + (Math.PI / 2);
}
```

It's a fairly simple example, but each time the method is called, we divide `Math.PI` by 2, add it to input, and return it to the calling statement.

Let's take that code and make the `Math.PI / 2` its own variable somewhere in the containing class:

```
private Double _halfPi = Math.PI / 2;

public Double HalfPiSomething(Int32 input)
{
    return input + _halfPi;
}
```

Obviously, taking the operation of `Math.PI / 2` and placing it in its own variable is a good idea just as basic coding practice, especially if said value is used in multiple points in the class... It's not here, but let's just pretend.

Finally, since `_halfPi` never changes let's make it `const`:

```
private const Double _halfPi = Math.PI / 2;

public Double HalfPiSomething(Int32 input)
{
    return input + _halfPi;
}
```

What I want to know is, other than being good coding practice for C# and making code easier to understand and harder to make errors with, are there benefits - especially regarding performance - to doing what I did above? Does the value stay in local memory longer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> each time the method is called, we divide `Math.PI` by `2`, add it to input, and return it to the calling statement.

No, that is not what is going on: C# compiler evaluates constant expressions at compile time. Moreover, when an expression that mixes constants and non-constants has sub-expressions that can be computed at compile time, the compiler precomputes the value as if it were a single constant.

The compiler identifies the `Math.PI / 2` sub-expression as a constant, performs the calculation, and produces the code that adds the input to a pre-computed result of the division.

> What I want to know is, other than being good coding practice for C# and making code easier to understand and harder to make errors with, are there benefits - especially regarding performance - to doing what I did above?

No, there is no reason to do compiler's job, unless it leads to more clarity.

> Does the value stay in local memory longer?

Constant values get "baked into" the code generated by the compiler. They are not part of the local data memory (although they are definitely in memory, for as long as the code is in memory).

Answer (score 3):

Most of these minor optimizations are handled for you by the compiler and the JIT. For example, If I compile your first chunk of code, the decompiled result is

```
    public double HalfPiSomething(int input)
    {
        return (double)input + 1.5707963267949;
    }
```

Because of this, I don't think it's worth worrying about these minor details from an optimization standpoint unless you have run into a serious performance issue, and then identify the chunk of code that is the bottleneck. After that, and on that focused bit of code, spending some time optimizing is worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

Standard warning: Try and measure different variants of code yourself for your particular case - `const`, `readonly`, fields/properties have different impact on performance and may differ.

Constant expressions are computed at compile time - so if all sub-expressions are constants you are not gaining anything by declaring additional constant:

```
const double halfPi = Math.PI / 2;
var r1 = halfPi * 3;    
var r2 = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
```

`r1` and `r2` will be initialized to exactly the same value.

Readonly are run-time values and calls may be inlined with JIT, but you still get pay of accessing fields.